# Site down but SSH and FTP work ok

Tags: apache

Haven't changed anything since it last worked (last night). Can connect via Putty and FileZille but none of my /www/ files work in web browser (Problem loading page). The IP also pings fine.

I've tried accessing site using both domain name and IP.

I've restarted apache2 as as well as the actual server, no luck.

Comment: there are lots of apache and system logs - have you checked their content ?

Comment: I used grep to find the log and got
"ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log",  that doesnt seem to tell me where it is!

Comment: I don't understand what you did with the logs... have you viewed them ?

Comment: no, i used grep to try and find where they were in order to read them. where can i find them? Clearly new at this :P

Comment: Check the apache docs (at http://apache.org IIRC) and check the docs of your OS (Linux ? Windows ? BSD ?)...

Comment: Ok the error log is mainly a load of "File does not exist" due to a bad image reference somewhere on my site, and a few "PHP Fatal errors" due to a "Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" on another php page, but neither of these should be the cause?

Comment: might be it... it depends on how your sites are configured etc. - SO is not the right site for these question... you might get some answer over at http://serverfault.stackexchange.com

Comment: PHP fatal errors will show a white page upon load unless you have display_errors set in your php.ini or .htaccess file.